# Mapping objects into CoreData with multiple foreign keys, without passing complete object, just FK ID

Tags: django, rest, restkit, tastypie

I have the following model in Django:

```
class Equipment(models.Model):
    model = models.ForeignKey(EquipmentModel)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True,verbose_name=_("Description"))
    serial = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=False, unique=True,
    production_line = models.ForeignKey(ProductionLine, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name=_("Production line"))
    plant = models.ForeignKey(Plant, verbose_name=_("Plant"))
```

Now, I was planning on deploying via REST a list of all the "production_line" and the equipment(s) they contain. However, each equipment has an "equipmentmodel" AND EACH "equipmentmodel" has another foreign_key to a "Manufacturer".

If I make a list of all the production lines and their equipment, do I have, for **each equipment** also give the complete "EquipmentModel" object, or can I how somehow pass only the ID of that model and still make the relationship in CoreData via RestKIT mappings? I would then fetch all the Manufacturers and their EquipmentModels. This would be way quicker than passing **for each** equipment, their respective Model and Manufacturer, as their will be a lot of repetitive data for the model and manufacturer. My question is therefore how can I map FK relationships with RestKIT and CoreData by passing the FK ID, and not the entire object in question?

I would like to still have a model like this however:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * serial;
@property (nonatomic, retain) PokaEquipmentModel *model;
@property (nonatomic, retain) PokaPlant *plant;
@property (nonatomic, retain) PokaProductionLine *productionLine;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use foreign keys to make the connection using RestKit. It requires only that the identity of the object to connect is supplied. That could be in the JSON if both objects are in the same response or part JSON and part in the URL path if the second object is being downloaded on demand.

Comment: You need to show your JSON and the basic mappings you have to create the objects. I can't just make it all up and have it make sense to you (without it being a full tutorial).

Comment: Here I created this pastebin. http://pastebin.com/47mgSt75 Basically, right now I was passing the complete objects in JSON, but it is way to slow. (Ie.: Each Equipment was also returning its complete EquipmentModel, which was returning its complete Manufacturer Model.) I changed it to only pass the _id this time, and I will fetch them later!

Comment: So, I'd suggest changing your JSON first, so it sends multiple top level items which are the `model overviews` (just ID and title) and the equipments. Then we can look at the mappings to read that in and connect. Then look at downloading the details for your partial model entity instances.

Comment: So, the production lines JSON structure needs to return the models, and within that, the array of equipment? That will be difficult with my current structure in Django.... [Sorry for being confused :(]

Comment: No, I'd remove all of the nesting (this is all just a suggestion) and return each set of information separately. I'd actually have multiple different calls available on the server, some returning partial data (identity and title) and some returning the detail for a specified item. One could also return an overview for a number of items at the same time. The idea being to make it easy to get an overview of the items and relationships without having to download all of the data for everything. This allows you to do quick searches and then fill in the details.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32833/discussion-between-abisson-and-wain)